# Merge webm video with audio

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am using below command to merge an audio with **webm video**.But the c

```
command = new String[]{"-i", inputvideoFileAbsolutePath, "-i", inputaudioFileAbsolutePath, "-c:v", "copy", "-c:a", "aac", "-map", "0:v:0", "-map", "1:a:0", "-shortest", outputFileAbsolutePath};
```

where outputFileAbsolutePath extension is mp4.

But the command fails with below error.However command seems to work fine with other input video formats(mp4,avi,mov,3gp).Why am i getting this error with webm video and how can i resolve it

Main error-

> Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters
>   ?): Invalid argument

Complete error-

```
 FAILED with output : ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
                                                                                            built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
                                                                                            configuration: --target-os=linux
    --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
    --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot
    --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include
    -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib
    -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=                                                                           libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
                                                                                            libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
                                                                                            libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
                                                                                            libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
                                                                                            libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
                                                                                            libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
                                                                                            libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
                                                                                            libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
                                                                                          Input #0, matroska,webm, from '/storage/emulated/0/Download/small.webm':
                                                                                            Metadata:
                                                                                              encoder         : Lavf53.17.0
                                                                                            Duration: 00:00:05.57, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 329 kb/s
                                                                                              Stream #0:0: Video: vp8, yuv420p, 560x320, SAR 1:1 DAR 7:4, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
                                                                                              Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: vorbis, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp (default)
                                                                                          Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #1.0 : stereo
                                                                                          Input #1, wav, from '/storage/emulated/0/Download/out.wav':
                                                                                            Metadata:
                                                                                              encoder         : Lavf57.76.100
                                                                                            Duration: 00:00:33.88, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
                                                                                              Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1411 kb/s
                                                                                          [mp4 @ 0xb61adc00] Could not find tag for codec vp8 in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container
                                                                                          Output #0, mp4, to '/storage/emulated/0/Movies/merge_video2.mp4':
                                                                                            Metadata:
                                                                                              encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
                                                                                              Stream #0:0: Video: vp8, yuv420p, 560x320 [SAR 1:1 DAR 7:4], q=2-31, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
                                                                                              Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
                                                                                              Metadata:
                                                                                                encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 aac
                                                                                          Stream mapping:
                                                                                            Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
                                                                                            Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
                                                                                          Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
                                                                                          [aac @ 0xb61fdc00] Qavg: nan
```

Comment: Replace `copy` with `libx264`

Comment: @Gyan Thanks..I have seen some video editing apps in which whatever is the input video file format they convert it into mp4 output video file format.I am confused whether conversion is required?is it ideal that my output video file  should have same extension as input video file?Example..3gp input video to 3gp output video,mkv to mkv ,avi to avi etc

Comment: MP4 and WebM are containers. They contain streams (audio, video..etc). Each stream is of a particular codec. A given container will not accept streams of all codecs. You can always transcode ("convert") any stream into a MP4 but only certain ones can be streamcopied (`copy`).

Comment: @Gyan If I want to support multiple video formats is it ideal that my output video file should have same extension as input video file?As you said a given container will not accept streams of all codecs,but a given output container will accept  streams of all codecs from input container if both are same and it will not involve boilerplate of transcoding?

Comment: Generally, yes. If you output to the same container, you can just do a remux (`copy`). The exceptions are when the input file is non-standard e.g. some Sony cameras produce MP4s with PCM audio which is not valid, so ffmpeg will not remux the audio into a MP4. But most of the time, it works.